# three.js Rotate 3d model left and right slowly

Tags: three.js

i'm trying to learn threejs but i've some difficult to understand how to rotate my 3d model.

now i'm able to rotate my model in a loop...but this is not what i want

i want to rotate my model a little bit to the right and then again a little bit to the left (in loop)..not at 360°.

or better ROTATE with mouse movement!

my code so far:

```
let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let computer;

function init(){
    container = document.querySelector('.scene');

    //creazione scena
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const fov = 35;
    const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 1000;

    // setup camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov,aspect,near,far);
    camera.position.set(0,2.8, 11);

    // luci ambiente
    const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040,3);
    scene.add(ambient);

    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(1,1,0);
    scene.add(light)

    // renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, alpha:true});
    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // caricamento modello 3d
    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('./3d/scene.gltf', function (gltf){
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        computer = gltf.scene.children[0];
        animate()
    })
}

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    computer.rotation.z += 0.003;
    computer.rotation.x = -1.2;
    computer.position.y = -10
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

init()

function onWindowResize(){
    camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
}
window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an option, use mouse position in NDC to slightly rotate your model:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.135.0";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

let g = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1, 2, 3, 4);
let m = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);  // let's suppose it's your model
scene.add(o);

window.addEventListener("pointermove", event => {
  let xMove = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1; // from the docs of Raycaster
  
  if (o) { // in case you load a model, you need to check if it's not null or undefined
    o.rotation.y = xMove * Math.PI * 0.1;
  }
  
});

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
</script>
```